# Using the DRY principle for functions with different return values and types

Tags: java, dry

Say I have two methods

```
public int findPages() {
    return this.selectors
        .getPagesSelector()
        .map(selector -> {
            Elements htmlElement = this.htmlPage.select(selector);
            return NumberUtils.toInt(htmlElement.text(), 1);
        })
        .orElse(1);
}
```

```
private String findPercent(Element product, double oldPrice, double newPrice) {
    return this.selectors
        .getPercentSelector()
        .map(selector -> {
            Elements htmlElement = product.select(selector);
            return StringUtils.defaultIfEmpty(htmlElement.text(), calculatePercent(oldPrice, newPrice));
        })
        .orElse(calculatePercent(oldPrice, newPrice));
```

The two do separate things and return different types but share code structures. Should I refactor the methods into a more abstract one for the sake of cleaner code, or is this not a violation of the DRY principle? Thanks!

Comment: They are same by coincidence. As you said, the two methods do different things. Don't couple them unnecessarily, let them as they are.

Comment: DRY can be, and often is, overdone.

Answer (score 2):

The DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle, as its name suggests is about not having several implementations of the same thing. You have two methods, `findPages` and `findPercent`. In their totality, these two methods are doing very different things, so they are not repetitive with one-another. So we look for partial matches, however, if we look at the code, we see some differences, so it is not really a partial match either. One is calling the `pagesSelector`, the other is calling the `percentSelector`. You could do some refactorization, like a method which would get a name of selector and return the correct selector, but this would be a large and complicated work, which is not worth doing unless you have a very good reason and for such a large work and small gain, having two similar-looking codes is not a valid reason. If you had to write this kind of code maybe 100 times, then it would make sense to either refactor your code or write a code generator and generate your methods with that.